# How to generate code coverage report in multi project builds using scct?

Tags: scala, sbt, scct

I am working on a multi project build. I have followed same instructions, as mentioned here http://mtkopone.github.io/scct/, to generate code coverage report.
I am able to see this message **scct: [testProject] Saving coverage data**. on console while running **sbt scct:test**. But can't see coverage report in this folder 
**$childProjectDir/target/scala_/coverage-report/**

Here is some source code of build.scala

```
lazy val root = Project("platform3", file("."))
.settings(ScctPlugin.mergeReportSettings: _*)
.aggregate(
  testProject
)
.settings(basicSettings: _*)


lazy val testProject = Project("testProject", file("testProject"))
.dependsOn(testUtil)
 .settings(noPublishing: _*)
.settings(libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  akkaKernel, 
  akkaSlf4j,
  jacksonScala,
  jodaTime,
  prettyTime,
  logback, 
 sprayCan,
  sprayRouting,
  specs2
))
.settings(ScctPlugin.instrumentSettings: _*)
```

The dependency, which I am using

```
// Scct Plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.sqality.scct" %% "sbt-scct" % "0.3")
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Ayush

Comment: I think `scct` is discontinued, and was replaced by [Scoverage](https://github.com/scoverage/scalac-scoverage-plugin). But even this more recent project has [a long-standing issue about multi-project builds](https://github.com/scoverage/scalac-scoverage-plugin/issues/24).

Comment: Happily, multi project support came with version 0.99.10 or 1.0.0 BETA (latest release is 1.0.1) https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage

Answer (score 0):

SCCT is obsolete, use [Scoverage](https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage) instead. Check out my working example of a multi-module SBT project which creates coverage reports for individual projects.
https://github.com/RadoBuransky/sonar-scoverage-plugin/tree/master/samples/sbt/multi-module